# Effective divisors of $X$ with $\operatorname{Pic}X\cong \mathbb Z$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-schemes

Consider $X$ a projective variety with $\operatorname{Pic}X\cong \mathbb Z$. So $\mathcal L\cong \mathcal O_X(m)$ for any invertible sheaf $\mathcal L$ and for some $m\in \mathbb Z$. I want to show that either $\mathcal O_X(m)$, $m>0$ have nonzero global sections or $\mathcal O_X(m)$, $m<0$ have nonzero global sections.

If $\mathcal L,\mathcal L^{-1}$ have nonzero global sections then $\mathcal L\cong \mathcal O_X$ so only one of $\mathcal O_X(-m),\mathcal O_X(m)$ has global sections ($m\neq 0$). But a priori there is no reason that if there are sheaves with nonzero global sections, they correspond to positive or negative integers. One could have that both $\mathcal O_X(-2),\mathcal O_X(3)$ have nonzero global sections, alternating the sign.

Since $X$ is projective we have a closed immersion $\iota\colon X\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^n_K$, so $\iota^*\mathcal O(1)$ is very ample and has global sections. So there exists some $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\mathcal O_X(k)$ has nonzero global section but it does not help much.

I guess showing that either $\mathcal O_X(1)$ or $\mathcal O_X(-1)$ has nonzero global sections would be enough. Indeed if $\mathcal O_X(1)$ has global sections, then any power $\mathcal O_X(m)$ has global sections, same for $\mathcal O_X(-1)$. But I don't know this is true. Any help ?

Comment: I don't quite understand te question. Is it that if all effective divisors are linearly equivalent to $\mathcal O_X(m)$ for some $m>0$, then $\mathrm{Pic}X\simeq\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @KentaS No not at all, I will try to edit. We suppose the isomorphism, and we know the form of the sheaves $(\mathcal O_X(m))$. Now I'm confident that we can separate these in two categories, those which are effective, and those which are not. Each one corresponds to a sign, so ether $\mathcal O_X(m)$ is effective for all $m>0$ and $\mathcal O_X(m)$ are not for all $m<0$ or vice versa. As I said both cannot correspond to effective divisors, one or the other. My concern is how can we be sure that for $m>0$ for example, all the sheaves have nonzero global sections.

Comment: @KentaS In fact it's precisely the converse of what you wrote. Suppose the isomorphism, how can we show that there exist sheaves with nonzero global sections (a priori it's not clear why it should exist for me) and that they correspond to $m>0$ (or $m<0$).

Comment: The fact that exactly one of L and L inverse has global sections if L is not trivial - is true for any proper variety irrespective of the Picard group.

Comment: @CraniumClamp There's at least some degree of subtlety here, as there exist line bundles which are strictly $\mathbb Q$-effective (i.e. $h^0(L)=0$ but $h^0(L^{\otimes m}) \ne 0$ for some $m > 1$). However the simplest example that I know of such a line bundle is over a certain rational surface of Picard rank $7$, so it does not apply to OP's question.

Comment: @TabesBridges: The simplest example is on a curve of genus 2.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Yes I agree. But in this case since all invertible sheaves are twisted it enables us to say that at most one of $\mathcal O_X(m),\mathcal O_X(-m)$ has nonzero global sections.

Comment: @TabesBridges Sure. But how can a very ample line bundle (which is OP’s case) fail to have global sections?! The OP is asking a terribly simple question.

Comment: @raisinsec obviously O_X(1) has global sections, it is very ample. You are complicating an extremely simple thing.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Obvious is not enough for me. Why does it have global sections ? As I said in my question I don't see why it should be the case, despite it being obvious.

Comment: @raisinsec by definition it is a very ample line bundle, nothing can be more obvious than a very ample line bundle having sections.

Comment: Yet again, this has nothing to do with whether Pic is Z or not.

Comment: @CraniumClamp I don't see why this is a concern for you. This might have nothing to to with the assumption, but if $\mathcal O_X(1)$ has global sections and $\operatorname{Pic}\mathbb Z$ $\mathcal O_X(1)$ generate all invertible sheaves so we know which one have global sections or not. Moreover I think you're mistaking $\mathcal O_X(1)$ and $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$. I doubt that $\mathcal O_X(1)$ is very ample by definition, although I agree with you that $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$ is. Here $X$ is any projective variety so why would $\mathcal O_X(1)$ be very maple "by definition" ?

Comment: This discussion just shows that you have no idea what the meaning of O_X(1) is, so there is no point in me saying anything more.

Comment: @CraniumClamp You do you.

Comment: @TabesBridges my earlier comment was inaccurate with half-sleep. What I meant to say is that at-most one of L and L dual has a section, if L isn’t trivial. But it is irrelevant to what the actual (simple) question is.

Comment: @CraniumClamp It is stated in the question. I joined the chat by the way.